# Problems when using release on NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ipad

I have a question on the topic of memory management. When I create a 
`NSMutableURLRequest` and I release it, after the method return the application crash.

If I remove the line with release on `NSMutableURLRequest` the application works. But it let memory leak.

What´s wrong?

This is the code:

```
- (NSString *) callServerWhaitReturn {

    NSMutableURLRequest * theRequest = [ NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: self.internalUrl] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 60.0];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"p1=%@", self.parameters] dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    NSURLResponse * response;
    NSError * error;
    NSData * result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &response error: &error];
    NSString * toReturn = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData: result encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@", toReturn );
    [theRequest release];
    if (response) {
        [response release];
    }
    if (result) {
        [result release];
    }
    [toReturn autorelease];
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Try using `[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL...`

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi Vaibhav Tekam . The error is not explicit. Simple the app crash. But you are right... I´m not using "alloc"! this is the problem. I try to release a object without alloc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:` returns an autoreleased object. If you haven't retained it, you shouldn't be releasing it.

Here are [the memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

Comment: Note that the same is true of your 'result' variable, so that release line will cause a crash as well. And you autorelease 'toReturn' twice, which will be yet another crasher.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableURLRequest * theRequest = [ NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: self.internalUrl] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 60.0];
```

is an auto-released object. You cannot `release` it. You have to allocate the object and take ownership only then you should `release` it. If you want to `release` it then `allocate` the object like this

```
NSMutableURLRequest * theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: self.internalUrl] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 60.0];
```

Comment: Tks a lot @7KV7 You answer complete the @morgan above! Again, tks

Answer (score 0):

You can't release `theRequest` because you did not allocate it.

So remove the below statement from your code.

```
[theRequest release];
```

use the `initWithURL` method of `NSMutableURLRequest`.